Symbolic link of all files in a folder to an existing folder
How can I create a symbolic link from the folder or files in the folder to a folder that already contains files?
so that when a new file is added to the original folder it is reflected in the other folder

Linking folder A to a subdirectory in an existing folder B seems the most logical.
ln -s A B/sub

If you do need to link files to an existing folder, you can link them one at a time. However, this would mean that you would have to manually link new files. This can be automated using a Python/Bash script and inotify, try searching for "continuous one-way sync".
